# How to pause Execution in SAS for milliseconds

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How to pause an execution for 5 milliseconds in SAS?

Can I use "CALL SLEEP (0.005)"

I have checked the below link but its confusing

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/n12ppys43orawkn1q0oxep4cmdk6.htm

Comment: Please show you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to try it out than to google:

```
data try_to_get_some_sleep;
    format n unit z5.3 evening morning expect measure time18.9 diff percent7.2;
    do unit = 5, 1, .5, .1, .01, .001;
        do n = .1, .9, 1.1, 1.9, 2 ;
            expect = n * unit;
            evening = time();
            call sleep (n, unit);
            morning = time();
            measure = morning - evening;
            diff = (measure - expect) / expect;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

results in

```
n       unit    evening             morning             expect              measure             diff
0.100   5.000   10:45:05.983414888  10:45:06.483422041  0:00:00.500000000   0:00:00.500007153   0.00%
0.900   5.000   10:45:06.483437061  10:45:10.984707117  0:00:04.500000000   0:00:04.501270056   0.03%
1.100   5.000   10:45:10.984720945  10:45:16.485454082  0:00:05.500000000   0:00:05.500733137   0.01%
1.900   5.000   10:45:16.485466003  10:45:25.984838009  0:00:09.500000000   0:00:09.499372005   (0.01%)
2.000   5.000   10:45:25.984853983  10:45:35.988686085  0:00:10.000000000   0:00:10.003832102   0.04%
0.100   1.000   10:45:35.988715887  10:45:36.088612080  0:00:00.100000000   0:00:00.099896193   (0.10%)
0.900   1.000   10:45:36.088624954  10:45:36.988639116  0:00:00.900000000   0:00:00.900014162   0.00%
1.100   1.000   10:45:36.988765001  10:45:38.089132071  0:00:01.100000000   0:00:01.100367069   0.03%
1.900   1.000   10:45:38.089145899  10:45:39.989645004  0:00:01.900000000   0:00:01.900499105   0.03%
2.000   1.000   10:45:39.989659071  10:45:41.989659071  0:00:02.000000000   0:00:02.000000000   0.00%
0.100   0.500   10:45:41.989671946  10:45:42.038803101  0:00:00.050000000   0:00:00.049131155   (1.74%)
0.900   0.500   10:45:42.038815975  10:45:42.488348961  0:00:00.450000000   0:00:00.449532986   (0.10%)
1.100   0.500   10:45:42.488362074  10:45:43.038013935  0:00:00.550000000   0:00:00.549651861   (0.06%)
1.900   0.500   10:45:43.038027048  10:45:43.987673044  0:00:00.950000000   0:00:00.949645996   (0.04%)
2.000   0.500   10:45:43.987685919  10:45:44.987751007  0:00:01.000000000   0:00:01.000065088   0.01%
0.100   0.100   10:45:44.987765074  10:45:44.996871948  0:00:00.010000000   0:00:00.009106874   (8.93%)
0.900   0.100   10:45:44.996876955  10:45:45.085994005  0:00:00.090000000   0:00:00.089117050   (0.98%)
1.100   0.100   10:45:45.086005926  10:45:45.195319891  0:00:00.110000000   0:00:00.109313965   (0.62%)
1.900   0.100   10:45:45.195332050  10:45:45.384675980  0:00:00.190000000   0:00:00.189343929   (0.35%)
2.000   0.100   10:45:45.384690046  10:45:45.585688114  0:00:00.200000000   0:00:00.200998068   0.50%
0.100   0.010   10:45:45.585701942  10:45:45.585707903  0:00:00.001000000   0:00:00.000005960   (99.4%)
0.900   0.010   10:45:45.585709095  10:45:45.595653057  0:00:00.009000000   0:00:00.009943962   10.5%
1.100   0.010   10:45:45.595659971  10:45:45.607652903  0:00:00.011000000   0:00:00.011992931   9.03%
1.900   0.010   10:45:45.607661009  10:45:45.626678944  0:00:00.019000000   0:00:00.019017935   0.09%
2.000   0.010   10:45:45.626689911  10:45:45.646678925  0:00:00.020000000   0:00:00.019989014   (0.05%)
0.100   0.001   10:45:45.646688938  10:45:45.646688938  0:00:00.000100000   0:00:00.000000000   ( 100%)
0.900   0.001   10:45:45.646689892  10:45:45.646689892  0:00:00.000900000   0:00:00.000000000   ( 100%)
1.100   0.001   10:45:45.646691084  10:45:45.647506952  0:00:00.001100000   0:00:00.000815868   (25.8%)
1.900   0.001   10:45:45.647507906  10:45:45.647620916  0:00:00.001900000   0:00:00.000113010   (94.1%)
2.000   0.001   10:45:45.647623062  10:45:45.650509119  0:00:00.002000000   0:00:00.002886057   44.3%
```

Comment: What do you think about the source of `diff`?

Answer (score 1):

The below shall stop the execution for 5 milliseconds in SAS.

```
data _null_;
    call sleep(5);
run;
```

You can use the *optional* unit argument to specify the unit of time in seconds, which is applied to *n*. Default is .001 (milliseconds). You can change it to seconds if you like

```
data _null_;
    call sleep(0.005,1);
run;
```

The above is equivalent to the former.

Comment: For testing I have used call sleep (10000,.001) ==> 10 seconds before inserting the timestamp, but the insert happened after 20 seconds .. Each record took 20 seconds if u see the timestamp difference
2022-07-14-12.18.21.075490
2022-07-14-12.18.41.172490,
2022-07-14-12.19.01.312540,
2022-07-14-12.19.41.467410,
2022-07-14-12.19.21.410270

Answer (score 0):

You can directly suspend a SAS session between steps using `%SYSCALL SLEEP(...` or `%SYSFUNC(SLEEP(...`  *NOTE: When using `%SYSCALL` you need to pass macro variables as the arguments, not numeric literal text*.

Example:

```
%let duration = 5;
%let unit = 0.001;

data one; set sashelp.class; run;
%syscall sleep(duration,unit);
data two; set sashelp.cars; run;
```

or

```
data one; set sashelp.class; run;
%let rc = %sysfunc ( sleep ( 5, 0.001 ));
data two; set sashelp.cars; run;
```